# directory with apache authentication but one file that open to everyone

Tags: apache

I would like to have directory protected with apache authentication but one file so I did:

<Directory /path/to/dir>

```
 AuthType Basic

 AuthName "Private  Pages"
 AuthBasicProvider file
 AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
 require user userid

 <FilesMatch "^exception.html$">
    Order Allow,Deny
    allow from All
 </FilesMatch>
```

</Directory>

But it not work all the files ask for password.
I tried also with \ before the dot in the file name and with :

```
<File exception.html>
```

Nothing help it ask for a password for all the files including exception.html

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should check out this similar question on serverfault:

[How to use basic auth for single file in otherwise forbidden Apache directory?](https://serverfault.com/questions/151240/how-to-use-basic-auth-for-single-file-in-otherwise-forbidden-apache-directory)